# Resizing a directx control automatically with the window form size?

Tags: c#, winforms

This app I am making is perhaps going to be deployed on machines with differing screen sizes. Whilst I am setting the form to be maximised by default, the size of the directx control (which I want maximised also) needs to be done manually at present in code which isn't ideal.  I wondered if there is an easy way to have it resize automatically with the size of the form window.

The winform is mazimised with:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

And the directx control window with:

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 1200);
```

I thought something like this would work, but it didn't (those properties aren't even available):

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Form.Height, Form.Width);
```

Sorry I am still very new!

Answer (score 0):

On the Form's resize event, you have to call directx device's reset method putting new presentationparameters in. Also, you should use XNA over Managed Directx..